# Bootstrap 5: Row of columns line up horizontally, or stack vertically, in different environments

Tags: multiple-columns, bootstrap-5

Experimenting with Bootstrap for a CS50 assignment.
Cannot get three columns to cross page horizontally.

col1  col2  col3

Instead they insist on stacking vertically.

```
col1
col2
col3
```

I took the code directly from the W3 grid tutorial for Bootstrap 5 (https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/bootstrap_grid_basic.php). On that page, under "Three Equal Columns," "Example", "Tryit Yourself", the code does exactly what I want. In VS Code (downloaded and running locally) there's some impediment unknown to me. Where should I be looking to troubleshoot?

Both environments link, in their html head, to the same version of Bootstrap's stylesheet (bootstrap.min.css) and script (bootstrap.bundle.min.js) via cdn.jsdelivr.net.
In their bodies, both set up a Bootstrap container in which to wrap a row, in which to wrap three columns.

My simple test code:

```
<main>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col">col 1</div>
   <div class="col">col 2</div>
   <div class="col">col 3</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</main>
```

I can't find anything wrong with that. Nevertheless Live Preview in VS Code presents three columns stacked.
I've spent two workdays searching for a solution, and none of the fixes in similar posts has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your reference have an error, try with this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col">col 1</div>
   <div class="col">col 2</div>
   <div class="col">col 3</div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I did check my Bootstrap references before posting. My html head includes: "<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>".

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Brandonjgs. My html head does contain the references you quote. Still doesn't work in VSCode.

Comment: Yes, you have a problem with the bootstrap reference, check your console. I'm gonna update my answer and you could copy all the code and test it.

Comment: For some reason the StackOverflow interface cut off my full script src link when I posted it, but I've checked the references several times and they're the same as yours. My Bootstrap references are part of the "distribution code" given by my Harvard course instructors, so I don't suppose I should overwrite them with something else. Can you pinpoint the "problem" you see?